# c# Fastest way to get values from string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# app that receives the following commands, via tcp sockets.

```
{
key = "foo",
value = 1.6557,
}
```

I'm currently using this method to get the key-value pairs and store them to a classes auto properties.

```
private Regex _keyRegex = new Regex("\"(.)*\"");
private Regex _valueRegex = new Regex(@"\d*\.{1}\d*");

private MyClass CrappyFunction(string nomnom)
{
  // Gets a match for the key
  var key = _keyRegex.Match(nomnom);
  // Gets a match for the value
  var value = _valueRegex.Match(nomnom);
  // Tests if got matches for both. If not, returns null.
  if (!key.Success || !value.Success) return null;
  // Found both values, so it creates a new MyClass and returns it
  // Also removes the " chars from the key 
  return new MyClass(
         key.ToString().Replace("\"", string.Empty),
         value.ToString());
}
```

Even though it works, I have a really bad feeling looking at this particular piece of code. It's ugly, in the sense that I'm using two regex objects to achieve my goal.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Is json comming in over the sockets, because there are libraries to parse that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a JSON library, you can combine the 2 regex expressions into one and use named groups `(?<name>expression)`.

```
private static Regex _regex =
    new Regex(@"""(?<key>.*)"".*?(?<value>\d*\.\d*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

The you get the result with

```
var match = _regex.Match("{ key = \"foo\", value = 1.6557, }");
string key = match.Groups["key"].Value;
string value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
```

Note that in a verbatim string, double quotes must be escaped by doubling them. The named group `key` does not include the double quotes, so you get the key directly.

So I basically have the regex

```
key_expression.*?value_expression
```

Both expressions are separated by `.*?`. The quotation mark tells the `*` to be lazy, i.e. to take as few characters as possible. If you don't, it will swallow the digits before the decimal point.

Answer (score -1):

May not be the fastest but using 'LINQ' and 'split' it is easy to extract out the values.

```
var keyValue = 
    data
    .Split(',')
    .Select(
        part => part.Split('='))
    .Take(2)
    .Select(
        parts => parts[1].Trim())
    .ToArray();

var key = keyValue[0].Replace("\"", string.Empty);
var value = keyValue[1];
```

First split is on the ','
 
The results of that is split on '='. 
Take(2), ignores the 3rd part of the first split.